# What is \null and when do we need to use it?

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

Up to now I don't understand well what `\null` actually is and when we need it. I have only known that it can be used to create hypothetical anchors as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\hfill xport \hfill\null\\
\null\hrulefill{} never \hrulefill\par
\hrulefill{} dies. \hrulefill\par
\hfill really? \hfill\null\par


\newpage
\null
\vfill
\hfill The End \hfill\null
\end{document}
```

1. What is `\null` and when do we need to use it?
2. Why do `\hrulefill` and `\hfill` need starting `\null` when they follow `\\` but not need `\null` when they follow `\par`?
3. Why does `\hfill` always need ending `\null` but `\hrulefill` not need it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. What is `\null` and when do we need to use it?
   `\null` is just `\hbox{}`. When is it needed? Never, actually.
2. Why do `\hrulefill` and `\hfill` need starting `\null` when they follow `\\` but not need `\null` when they follow `\par`?
   `\hrulefill` is `\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hfill\kern0pt`, so it's not exactly like `\hfill`, as it adds a null kern after it, but very similar to it. The difference between `\par\hrulefill` and `\\\hrulefill` is that after a `\par` there's a box (the indent box, even with `\noindent`), but after `\\` there's no box on the line, so glue disappears (and leaders, also).
3. Why does `\hfill` always need ending `\null` but `\hrulefill` not need it?
   Because of the `\kern0pt` at the end of `\hrulefill`.
4. Why is the first line after `\begin{document}` not regarded as a paragraph recall that starting `\null` is needed by `\hfill` there?
   Could you be more precise about this?

Comment: Is it really _never_ necessary? For example if I have some environment, which expects to find some text, but I want to tell it "take no text as text", what would be the way to not use something like `\null` and still tell Tex that there is empty space? (for example with tabulars with alignments)

Comment: @Zelphir The question is about `\null` in the document body. If you know what you're doing, using it in the definition of an environment might be justified. Remember that it never starts or ends horizontal mode.

Comment: Actually `\null` is useful when one needs to ensure the correct behavior of `\nofrenchspacing` mode, which makes spaces after each sentence longer. By default, if a sentence ends in capital letter, TeX thinks it is an initial, and does not implement longer spacing, even though it may be desirable. To ensure the longer space happens, one can insert `\null` right before the ending punctuation sign. For example the sentence `In USA we don't usually drink tea with milk, like they do in the UK\null.` will produce a longer space after the period, than without `\null'.

Comment: @mathreader LaTeX has `\@` for that, which can be used before or after punctuation; in the latter case it poses no problem for following spaces.

Answer (score 28):

TeX ignores spaces in some situation if there is no material. `\null` is the same as `\hbox{}` and it can be used for a material which reserves no space but shows TeX that there is a box which is taken into account for typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
     \parindent=0pt          
\begin{document}     
\hfill xport \hfill\null          

\hrulefill never \hrulefill          

\hrulefill dies \hrulefill          
\newpage
 \null \vfill     
\hfill The End \hfill\null     
\vfill     
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `\null` is useful when one needs to ensure the correct behavior of `\nofrenchspacing` mode, which makes spaces after each sentence longer. By default, if a sentence ends in capital letter, TeX thinks it is an initial, and does not implement longer spacing, even though it may be desirable. To ensure the longer space happens, one can insert `\null` right before the ending punctuation sign. For example the sentence `In USA we don't usually drink tea with milk, like they do it in the UK\null.` will produce a longer space after the period, than without `\null`, if the option `\nofrenchspacing` is enabled.

I encountered this usage in the book `TeX for the Impatient' by Paul W. Abrahams, Kathryn A. Hargreaves, and Karl Berry, available here:
http://tug.ctan.org/info/impatient/book.pdf

Comment: As far as I remember, “TeX for the impatient” is about plain TeX. In LaTeX there's `\@` that's even more efficient than `\null`. I still claim that `\null` should *never* be used in a LaTeX document (possible exception for the preamble).

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I did not know about `\@`. It is indeed easier to type.