# Place parentheses around a cross-reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Is possible to surround a cross-reference with brackets or parentheses? For example when I write a command like `some text \ref{some label}` then when compiled the output was **some text (12)** without manually placing parentheses in latex  command, like `some text (\ref{some label})`.

Comment: In case of equations, there is `\eqref` of package `amsmath` that adds parentheses around the equation number.

Comment: If I need to apply that for any referencing, not just the equation??

Comment: Have a good look at the `cleveref` package. It is (a) fully compatible with the `hyperref` package (and must be loaded after `hyperref`) and (b) allows full customization of the appearance of cross-references.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing hyperlink/hyperref with "cross-reference" since that's what your posting is mainly about. (A hyperlink is a special type of a cross-reference.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could renew the reference command, perhaps something like:

```
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}
\begin{document}

\section{Section heading}\label{sec:testlabel}

Reference: \ref{sec:testlabel}
\end{document}
```

Note: as mentioned by @Mico, this solution isn't compatible with `hyperref` package.

Comment: You should probably provide a note that this solution isn't compatible with `hyperref`: regardless of whether that package is loaded before or after your code, the result is that no parentheses will be placed around the section number.

Answer (score 51):

Try using `\eqref{fig:label}` from the `amsmath` package.

(Taken from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latexusersgroup/e1CHoBfj8pQ)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The OP has stated in a comment that he (?) needs to parentheses to be placed around *all cross-referencing call-outs*, not just around call-outs to equations. Thus, your answer doesn't address the query fully.

Comment: you are right, and I just read some comments about the issue on the OP. I'll remove my answer soon. Sorry and thank you for your comment.

Comment: Upvoted for the equation-only option.

Comment: @Mico Haven't tried other stuff yet, but `\eqref` works well w/ enumeration items (besides equations)

Comment: Glad you didn't remove it: despite what the OP requested, it's a very helpful answer

Answer (score 14):

I prefer the `autoref` function provided in the hyperref package.

Taking examples for tables and figures:

```
The Table reference is \autoref{tab:VHTRC}.
The equation reference is \autoref{eq:3}.
```

Next, new reference styles should be renewed at the preamble.
Usually I define them just after including the hyperref package.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Equation (#1)\null}
```

The `\def` define the auto-reference variable `#1` in the style `Equation (#1)`, which is enclosed in `()`.
Then you will get the result like this:

[image]

If you want to use curly braces `{}`, they should be escaped with the `\`.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Equation \{#1\}\null}
```

Comment: This is dark magic for me. I usually do things like `\newcommand{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}` to change what comes before the reference number. But I have no idea why `~#1\null` works at all.

Comment: There is already question about `\null`:
 [macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/what-is-null-and-when-do-we-need-to-use-it). It only **reserves no space but shows TeX that there is a box which is taken into account for typesetting**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried cmhughes' answer in my code, it didn't work (no parentheses -- which is strange, because the minimal example worked). guest2015's worked, but required an extra package. I ended up using `\newcommand\pef[1]{(\ref{#1})}`