# \equationautorefname not working (hyperref package)

Tags: equations, hyperref, brackets

It's one hour that I'm trying to change the name of reference from "Equation 1" to "(eq.1)". I found the following [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172736/place-parentheses-around-a-cross-reference)

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Equation (#1)\null}
```

but it does not change anything.
I thought it was a conflict with amsmath, but even eliminating it, it does not work.
How can I implement that without loosing cross-reference link or without simply writing ref comand between parenthesis?

As stiffly requested, there's an example code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

There is the equation \autoref{eq:test}\\
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: provide a small but complete example that can be used for a test. Snippets are useless.

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a current LaTeX you can make use of `\labelformat` and actually don't need autoref:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\labelformat{equation}{(eq.~#1)}
\def\equationautorefname#1{}%for autoref, gobble the space
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation}    
        E=mc^2  \label{eq:einstein}
    \end{equation}

    See the great equation \ref{eq:einstein}, \autoref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It kinda works, but I have the package \usepackage[english]{babel} that write down "Equation (eq.1)" and not only "(eq.1)". I'll upload a good example to the main post now.

Comment: sorry but I won't expand my answer. Next time provide an example directly.

Comment: Don't mind, thank you anyway! At least I'm closer to the answer due to your contribute :)

Comment: I just realized that using \ref instead of \autoref does the tricks using your solution! :P
Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [schtandard's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584601/161015)
who said

> A bit of a dirty hack, but this works as long as `hyperref` does not
> change its `\autoref` implementation.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\equationautorefname{(eq.} 

%From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584601/161015
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\plain@equationautorefname\equationautorefname
    \def\equationautorefname{\plain@equationautorefname\@autoref@insert@tagform}%
    \def\@autoref@insert@tagform~#1\null{\,#1)\null}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation}    
        E=mc^2  \label{eq:einstein}
    \end{equation}

    See the great equation \autoref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would prefer something less "hacky".
Anyway thank you very much! :)