# Unwanted Empty Pages, using style file given by university

Tags: titles

My university has a titlepage template that they want us to use for the masters thesis.

However, it adds an additional empty page before and after the titlepage (gives two afterwards, so one unwanted). 
I found out that short titles dont have the problem. Any ideas how to fix it? It doesn't help if I break my title manually.

Also, the name of the university ends up on the third page sometimes...

The sty file we are given is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MA_Titlepage}[2010/04/25]


\newcommand*{\betreuer}[1]{\def\@betreuer{#1}}
\betreuer{}
\newcommand*{\ausarbeitungstyp}[1]{\def\@ausarbeitungstyp{#1}}
\ausarbeitungstyp{}
\newcommand*{\geburtsdatum}[1]{\def\@geburtsdatum{#1}}
\geburtsdatum{}
\newcommand*{\geburtsort}[1]{\def\@geburtsort{#1}}
\geburtsort{}
\newcommand*{\institut}[1]{\def\@institut{#1}}
\institut{}
\newcommand*{\authornew}[1]{\def\@authornew{#1}}
\authornew{}

\renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil

\begin{center}%

\parbox{10cm}{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries \@title \par\end{center}}\\
\vspace{1em}
{\Large
\vspace{1em}
\@authornew}\\
\vspace{1em}
Born   \@geburtsdatum \ in \@geburtsort\\
\vspace{1em}
{\large \@date}
\vspace{15em}

{\large \@ausarbeitungstyp}\\
\vspace{1em}
{\large \@betreuer}\\
\vspace{1em}
\centerline{{\large\sc \@institut}}
\vspace{15em}

\centerline{{\large\sc Mathematische Fakult\"at der}}
\vspace{1em}
\centerline{{\large\sc Universitaet Nordpol}}

\end{center}

\vfil\null
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\end{titlepage}

  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}


\endinput
```

and I am currently using it via

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{MA_Titlepage}

\authornew{X Y}
\geburtsdatum{1st April 1900}
\geburtsort{New York, U.S.A.}
\date{\today}

\betreuer{Advisor: Prof. Dr. Z Z}
\institut{Mathematical Institute}

\title{This is only an example}

\ausarbeitungstyp{Master's Thesis  Mathematics}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

If I replace "This is only an example" by "example" I get what I want.

Comment: Did you check the license/copyright for publishing that package?

Comment: it's publicly available on the universities homepage

Comment: Can you share a link and add it to the question above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm an "interesting" set of macros:-)

Assuming you don't want to get into discussions about changing your institution's template you could do

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{MA_Titlepage}

\authornew{X Y}
\geburtsdatum{1st April 1900}
\geburtsort{New York, U.S.A.}
\date{\today}

\betreuer{Advisor: Prof. Dr. Z Z}
\institut{Mathematical Institute}


\title{This is only an example}


\ausarbeitungstyp{Master's Thesis  Mathematics}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vspace*{-60pt}
    \maketitle
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would actually prefer making a minor change to the template (as long as the fonts and fontsizes stay the same) than having that ugly \vspace in MY text :) Tell me what you think is off in the template and it shall be changed :)

Comment: @Bananach I started do do that but basically it needs rewriting, It shouldn't have `\null` it shouldn't have `\vfill` it shouldn't have `\centerline` it shouldn't have `\sc` it probably shouldn't have the two `\clearpage` it shouldn't have `{\large..}` without a paragraph break before the `}` and that's just a first look:-) Obviously you could push the minipage and vspace that I suggest here into the start and end of the definition of `\maketitle` in the package, so your document just has `\maketitle`

Comment: Hm, I will talk to my advisor about using a different template/changing the official template. I guess there is no point in all students figuring the changes out themselves

Answer (score 4):

The command `\null\vfil` seems to be wrong there, but the template looks a little bit weird, in my point of view. (See [What is \null and when do we need to use it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/what-is-null-and-when-do-we-need-to-use-it) on `\null` please)

Instead of directly editing the template (well, one should do that anyway) a quick solution is to patch out the `\null\vfil` command using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{MA_Titlepage}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\null\vfil}{}{}{}


\authornew{X Y}
\geburtsdatum{1st April 1900}
\geburtsort{New York, U.S.A.}
\date{\today}

\betreuer{Advisor: Prof. Dr. Z Z}
\institut{Mathematical Institute}



\title{This is only an example}

\ausarbeitungstyp{Master's Thesis  Mathematics}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will just remove it in the template. What else do you think is off? Also if you say I can just remove the two commands, do you know what they were supposed to be good for?